# Why is public/private such an important programming aspect?

Tags: objective-c, oop

Why do in most programming languages do you get the ability to have private and or public methods/functions classes and properties?

Does it make much of a difrence to let's say.. have all classes, methods and properties be public?

I know that if you have all your methods, classe ans properties set to private nothing will work.
So at least I know that much.

But does the distinction between the two matter? What's the big deal if one class knows another Class "that is meant to be private" exists?

Comment: It isn't the classes which are the problem - its other developers using them. By restricting access, you are clearly indicating what the designed interface to a class should be (and which methods are off limits). Private methods allow you to refactor large functions internally, without committing to keeping them / allowing changes in future versions.

Comment: It's critically important or not important at all, depending on your point of view (and, to some extent, the nature of the application).  Objective-C doesn't really have "private", of course, just "obscured".

Comment: It's about maintainability. To your external customers you are responsible only for your public interface, and the less you have to be responsible for the better. Anything that's public *will* be used by users, and then you can never ever change it. To witness the full horror of the consequences, look at MS WIndows.

Comment: The point is to reduce dependencies on implementation details that are not guaranteed to remain the same. This becomes increasingly important as an application's codebase increases in complexity, and is particularly important for libraries and frameworks. If users of a framework write code that depends on its internal implementation details, new versions of the framework are more likely to cause breakage.

Answer (score 2):

When you make something public, you enter a contract with the user class: "Hey, this is, what I offer, use it or not." Changing the public interface is expensive, because you have to change all code using that public interface, too. Think of a developer of a framework like Cocoa used by thousands of developers. If you change one public methods, for example removing one, thousands of apps break. They have to be changed, too.

So making everything public simply means that you cannot change anything anymore. (You can, but the people will get angry at one point.)

Let's think of having a class implementing a list. There is a method to sort it: sortListWithKey. You make that public because you want the users of the class to get a sorted list. This is good.

There are several algorithms for sorting. Let's say, you implement one that needs to calculate the meridian (the middle element). You need this method internally for your sorting algorithm. So it is enough, to implement it privately. Changing the whole structure of data holding including the implemented sorting algorithm is no problem and will not break existing code using that class.

But if you made the meridian method public (remember: you implemented it, because you needed it internally), you still have to keep it, even the new sorting algorithm does not need it. You cannot remove it anymore, even with the new structure it is very hard (and/or expensive) to keep the method.

So make that part of your implementation public that is useful for the users, but no more. Otherwise you shackle yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If humans had perfect memory, documentation and communication skills, and made no mistakes, then there might not be a useful difference.  But using or changing something from the wrong file and then forgetting about it (or not documenting it clearly for the rest of the team, or yourself in the future) is too common a cause of hard-to-find bugs.

Marking things private makes it a bit more work to create the same types of bugs, and thus less likely that lazy/sleepy programmers will do all that extra work just to mess up the application.

Answer (score 0):

In computer science it is called **information hiding**. You, as a programmer, want to offer only necessary methods or properties to other programmers which will use your public API and this is the way how you can achieve so-called **low coupling** between modules.

Comment: Don't you mean 'low coupling between modules?'

Comment: oh you are totally right.  I was thinking about cohesion and coupling at the same time. Now, it's fixed. Thanks